# Setting priority only in Firebase's onDisconnect()

Tags: java, firebase

In Firebase's `onDisconnect()` handler, you can easily use `setValue()` to update the reference to another value or `remove()` to delete that reference.

For `setValue()`, there are also variants that include the priority value.

But what is the best practice if you want to update the priority value *only*, and not the value?

Something like `onDisconnect().setPriority(Double.MAX_VALUE)` seems to be missing.

Manually getting the current value at the given reference again and passing this value to `setValue()` is not only too complicated but also not possible as a last, fast action when the user has disconnected.

**Edit:**

`onDisconnect()` cannot even be used with `onDisconnect().removeValue()` or `onDisconnect().setValue(null)` at all. The problem is that you cannot disconnect the user manually, can you? This cannot be the optimal solution: As it is now, you have to wait for Java's GC to clear all the Firebase references, and hopefully then, at least, the connection will be closed so that the `onDisconnect()` callbacks will be fired, won't it?

Comment: As you've stated, there is no setPriority() for onDisconnect(). Can you share the use case you're trying to satisfy? It would probably be easier to come up with creative solutions if we had the root problem.

Comment: This is an inconsistency in the API: Every Firebase reference has `setValue(value, priority)` and `setPriority(priority)`. In contrast, `onDisconnect()` has `setValue(value, priority)` while it _does not_ have `setPriority()`. Does that make sense? The problem: I maintain a list of all users in `/users` and store all profile data there. In order to provide a list of users that are online right now, I use `setPriority(1)` on the user reference when the user signs in. If I could use `setPriority(0)` on `onDisconnect()`, I could show presence with `startAt(1)`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Of course, I could maintain an additional list of users that are online right now in, say, `/users_online`. But saving the state there would be redundant and inefficient. Why do that if one could make the API more consistent and solve this problem more easily? Or am I missing any simple solution?

Comment: You're right that it's missing. Regarding onDisconnect's missing setPriority method, Andrew says "Yes, we do intend to add this in the future! No ETA at this time." - dated 5 July 2013 at:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/c8ppWeU4dLo

Comment: @leanne Thank you! Does anyone know a good workaround for now?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no `setPriority()` for `onDisconnect()` at this time.

However, Firebase has [mentioned](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/c8ppWeU4dLo) their intention to add this feature in a future release, "Yes, we do intend to add this in the future! No ETA at this time."